# give all elements an ID of matched content from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to give all `<span>` tags an id of whatever their content matches to array1.

```
array1 = ["155","80","200","123"];

<span>155</span>
<span>80</span>
<span>200</span>
<span>123</span>
```

The end result being:

```
<span id="155">155</span>
<span id="80">80</span>
<span id="200">200</span>
<span id="123">123</span>
```

Here the best I can muster:

```
var arr = $('span:contains(array1[i])');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].id = i;
}
```

I am neither savvy with JavaScript or arrays.
Any Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Don't do this! You already have references to those array elements. Why query your presentation layer for data?

Comment: how did those items get in the HTML in the first place?

Comment: Seems absurd to me. Please explain the final purpose of what you are trying to achieve, and how you get the array and generate the spans in the first place.

Comment: The content in the spans are generated by a form. I put them into an array using .innerHTML. I now realize that there is a possibility for duplicate numbers, however. Fortunately the order in which the numbers are placed into the array will always correspond with their index number. So I am going use the index as an ID instead. The purpose of giving these spans an ID is so I can link the content to another input box on another generated form. The reason for such convoluted coding is because I have no control over what is generated on the two forms I am linking together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all elements with tag name `span` :

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var len = s.length;
```

Now, in a for loop, give each element their IDs :

```
for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var inner = s[i].innerHTML;
    s[i].id = inner;
```

This will give respective IDs to all spans.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
array1 = ["155","80","200","123"];

for(var i = 0;i < array1.length; i++) {
    $("span:contains("+ array1[i] +")").each(function(ind, val){
        if($(val).html() == array1[i])
            $(val).attr("id", array1[i]);
    })
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `each` here. If the selector returns more than one result, you really shouldn't set the ids of all those elements to be the same.

Comment: @MattBurland i posted comment on your answer. what if any situation like that. and it would not set id of all matched selectors. i have checked for exact same content.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd thing to do, and you should probably rethink it and find a better approach, but this will do what you wanted:

```
array1 = ["155","80","200","123"];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    var arr = $('span:contains(' + array1[i] + ')').first();
    console.log(arr);
    arr.attr("id",array1[i]);
}
```

Comment: any span containing "hello 155 voters" something like will break this code

Comment: @RashminJaviya: which is why it isn't a good idea to start with. But if you have to. And are confident there aren't any other rogue `span` floating around.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrodriguezr/9SRLH/1/)

```
$(function(){
    var arr = $('#spans').find('span');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $(arr[i]).attr('id',i);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
var array1 = ["155","80","200","123"];

$("span").filter(function() { 
    var idx = $.inArray( $.trim($(this).text()), array1);
    if( idx > -1 ) {
        return $(this).attr("id", array1[idx]);
    }
});
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UjDVe/)

Answer (score -1):

with jquery you can do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    $(this).attr("id",array1[i]);    
}
```

OR if the spans are already populated with HTML (not sure how they would be, just saying)

```
$( "span" ).each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id") = $(this).html();
})
```